# Collapse space after translate in WP7/XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a simple Windows Phone 7 app (Silverlight/XAML/C#) with a `StackPanel` containing some `TextBlock` elements.

However, if I translate one of these `TextBlock` elements (via `RenderTransform` using `TranslateTransform` to specify the new x/y-position), then the `TextBlock` still retains its original space in the `StackPanel`. As such, there's a 'hole' in the layout where the `TextBlock` was prior to being transformed (which I guess is a consequence of the way transforms are rendered).

My question is: **can an element's original space be 'collapsed' after being transformed?** I know how to do this in good old HTML/CSS, but I don't know about Silverlight/XAML. I've tried a few methods, but nothing has worked so far (right now I'm just compensating by altering the margins on the surrounding `TextBlock` elements, but this seems an ugly way of doing things).

If it's not possible to 'collapse' the original space, is there another way to alter an element's relative x/y position (I'm not really free to use `Canvas` in this situation)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're sure the element that is transformed will always be "missing" from the StackPanel, you could give it a negative bottom margin equal to the TextBlock's ActualHeight, which will pull the items below it upward.

Failing that, another path would be to create a `UserControl` with the StackPanel inside it, and implement `MeasureOverride` and/or `ArrangeOverride`.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I ended up using negative margins in the end, which seem to work fairly well. Thanks for your help!